# PDO DELETE is not deleting all the row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the codes following for a delete process;

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteSong'])) {
    $id = $_POST['deleteSong'];

    $delete = $connect->prepare('DELETE FROM lyrica_songs WHERE id = ?');
    $delete->execute(array($id));

    $error = TRUE;
  }
```

These codes is not deleting row. I have 7 columns at lyrica_songs and 3 of them are integers. ID (auto increment), song_singer_id and song_hit and when i run my codes ID, song_singer_id, song_hit are not deleted. I tried making them text instead integers and ID and song_hit still can't be deleted.

EDIT:

My connection code

```
<?php 
    $db_host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lyrica;charset=utf8'; 
    $db_username = 'root'; 
    $db_password = ''; 
    try { 
        $connect = new PDO($db_host,$db_username,$db_password); 
        $connect->exec('SET NAMES UTF-8; SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8'); 
    } catch (PDOException $error) { 
        echo "Veritabanı bağlantısı kurulamadı: " . $error->getMessage(); 
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting `$error = TRUE;` for no apparent reason?

Comment: Are you sure you are using PDO, can we see the way you connect to the database please so we are sure

Comment: $error for redirecting user from lyrics.php?id=$id to lyrics.php. I am using it for a condition. These are my codes for connecting to database. `$db_host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lyrica;charset=utf8';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

try {
  $connect = new PDO($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);
  $connect->exec('SET NAMES UTF-8; SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8');
} catch (PDOException $error) {
  echo "Veritabanı bağlantısı kurulamadı: " . $error->getMessage();
}`

Comment: Edit your connection code. `$connect->exec('SET NAMES UTF-8; SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8');`. You missed a single quote after the last `UTF-8`.

Comment: I deleted it while i am posting here, here is the original of that line: $connect->exec('SET NAMES `UTF-8`; SET CHARACTER SET `UTF-8`');

Comment: where's the form for this? we don't know if there's something wrong in there.  You're also not checking for errors in any way.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($POST)` and let us know what the output is.

Comment: There was a problem with my form, i solved it. Thank you so much for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

PDO version of @ChukwuemekaInya code

```
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_username = 'root'; 
$db_password = '';

try {
  $query = "DELETE FROM `lyrica_songs` WHERE `id`=:id ";

  $dB = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=lyrica", $db_username, $db_password);
  $stmt = $dB->prepare($query);

  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  return $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_username = 'root'; 
$db_password = ''; 

try { 
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=lyrica",$db_username,$db_password);
} catch (PDOException $error) { 
    echo "Veritabanı bağlantısı kurulamadı: " . $error->getMessage(); 
}

$delete = $connect->prepare('DELETE FROM lyrica_songs WHERE id = :id');
$delete->bindParam(':id', $id);
$delete->execute(); 
$delete->close();
```

Comment: That's `mysqli` syntax. OP is using `PDO`.

Comment: @simon ... Oh. Thanks. I missed that part.

Comment: @cemekkazan ... I don't understand how it is working if you can't delete your rows... Try again now. I just edited my solution.

Comment: I am very sorry i wrote it wrong, it must have been 'not'. And still, it is not working.